# Parsing Juniper firewall logs to a text file in Perl

Tags: perl, logging

I am new to Perl and programming. I have limited exposure to writing shell scripts in Unix and have been using the Camel book *Programming Perl, 3rd Edition* as well as various perl tutorials I've come across on the web. I am trying to take a log file created nightly by our Juniper firewall and create a report on the VPN sessions for research purposes. I am in the process of writing and revising a script that will read the log file, parse out several variables from each line of the log and output a report to a text file formatted like this:

```
UserID DHCP          Logon    Timeout  Maxsession Logout   Closed   Duration
User1  xxx.xx.xxx.xx 06:23:47                     06:20:45 06:20:45 00:14:33
User2  xxx.xx.xxx.xx 08:01:59          16:01:59            16:01:59 00:57:27
User3  xxx.xx.xxx.xx 09:04:20 09:14:20                     09:14:24 00:10:00
User1  xxx.xx.xxx.xx 17:01:01                     18:05:01 18:05:01 01:04:00

The three cases I am interested in capturing are:
 1. User logs in, user logs out
 2. User logs in, user times out
 3. User logs in, max session reached user times out
```

I am unsure what to do with the time stamps to get some of the durations that are not provided by some of the events. Sometimes the session duration is provided but for events where it is not I need to figure out how to normalize the applicable timestamps and do a calculation to get it. Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated thank you!

**Actions:**

When a user logs in the following line is generated in the log file:

> Nov  30 09:02:45 100.10.10.100 Juniper: 2014-12-08 09:02:02 - ive - [101.10.100.10] DOMAIN\user(myRealm)[myRole] - VPN Tunneling: Session started for user with IPv4 address 100.11.11.123, hostname userHostName

When a user logs out the following lines are generated in the log file:

> Nov  30 14:30:52 100.10.10.100 Juniper: 2014-11-30 14:30:22 - ive - [10.1.100.100] user1(vpn1) [vpn1] - Logout from 100.10.10.100 (session:12345678)
>
> Nov  30 14:30:52 100.10.10.100 Juniper: 2014-11-30 14:30:22 - ive - [10.1.100.100] user1(vpn1) [] - Closed connection to 100.10.10.1 after 1234 seconds, with 1234567 bytes read and 123456789 bytes written

When a user times out the following lines are generated in the log file:

> Nov  30 14:30:52 100.10.10.100 Juniper: 2014-11-30 14:30:22 - ive - [10.1.100.100] user1(vpn1) [] - Closed connection to 100.10.10.1 after 1234 seconds, with 1234567 bytes read and 123456789 bytes written
>   Nov  30 14:30:52 100.10.10.100 Juniper: 2014-11-30 14:30:22 - ive - [10.1.100.100] user1(vpn1) [vpn1] - Session timed out for user/vpn1 (session:00000000) due to inactivity (last access at 13:43:20 2014/11/30).

When a user reaches the maximum session timeout the following lines are generated in the log file:

> Nov  30 14:30:52 100.10.10.100 Juniper: 2014-11-30 14:30:22 - ive - [10.1.100.100] user1(vpn1) [vpn1] - Max session timeout for user/vpn1 (session:00000000)
>   Nov  30 14:30:52 100.10.10.100 Juniper: 2014-11-30 14:30:22 - ive - [10.1.100.100] user1(vpn1) [] - Closed connection to 100.10.10.1 after 1234 seconds, with 1234567 bytes read and 123456789 bytes written

**My code so far:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

#This script convert the specified log file to a report showing each user's ID, DHCP Address, Logon time,
#Logout time, Timeout time, and Maxtimout time. 

#Arrays needed for script
my @fields;
my @user;
my @dhcp;
my @login;
my @logout;
my @close;
my @timeout;
my @maxtimeout;

#Scalars needed for script
my $localtime = localtime();
my $input = '/home/user/bin/Temp/log.txt';
my $output = '>/home/user/bin/Temp/vpnreport.txt';
my $line;
my $fields;
my $userid;
my $jdate;
my $jtime;
my $dhcpaddr;
my $srcaddr;
my $sessionid;
my $sessiondur;
my $lastacctime;
my $lastaccdate;
my $bytesr;
my $bytesw;
my $timestamp;
my $maxrow = 0;
my $currow = 0;
my $i = 0;

#Open the log file
open (VPNLOG, $input) or die "Unable to open the input file:$!\n";

#Open the file(s) to be written to in clobber mode
open (VPNREPORT, $output) or die "Unable to open the output file:$!\n";

#Setup to while loop to process each line
while ($line = <VPNLOG>) {
chomp $line; #Remove the line breaks

#Strip the log's timestamp and IP
$line =~ s/.*Juniper:\s(.*)$/$1/;

#If line contains "Administrators" or "(Admin Users)" ignore it and move on to the next line
unless ($line =~ m/Administrators|(Admin Users)|System()/) {
#Split the line into the @fields array on every " " encountered
@fields = split (/ /, $line);
$jdate = $fields[0];                     #Juniper datestamp
$jdate =~ s/-//g;                        #Remove any occurance of "-" from the date stamp
$jtime = $fields[1];                     #Juniper timestamp
$userid = $fields[6];                    #User ID
$userid =~ s/XXXXXXX.|\(.*\)\[(.*)\]//g; #Remove the "XXXXXXX\" preceding the username and the "(Realm)[Role    ]"
                                         #trailing the username
#Normalize and recombine jtime and jdate here:
$timestamp = "$jdate $jtime";
#Check to see if line contains string "VPN Tunneling: Session started for user"

if ($line =~ m/VPN Tunneling: Session started for user/) {
    ++$maxrow;
    $dhcpaddr = $fields[17];          #Destination IP address
    $dhcpaddr =~ s/,//g;              #Remove "," trailing the IP address
    $user[$maxrow] = $userid;
    $dhcp[$maxrow] = $dhcpaddr;
    $login[$maxrow] = $timestamp;
    $logout[$maxrow] = "--";
    $close[$maxrow] = "--";
    $timeout[$maxrow] = "--";
    $maxtimeout[$maxrow] = "--";
    }

elsif ($line =~m/Logout/) {
    $dhcpaddr = $fields[10];           #DHCP IP address
    $sessionid = $fields[11];          #Session ID
    $sessionid =~ s/\(session:|\)//g;   #Remove the "(session:" and ")" from the session ID
    for ($currow = $maxrow; $currow >= 1; $currow--) {
        if ($user[$currow] eq $userid and $logout[$currow] eq "--") {
            $logout[$currow] = $timestamp;
            last;
        }
    }
}

elsif ($line =~m/Closed connection/) {
    $dhcpaddr = $fields[11];         #DHCP IP Address
    $sessiondur = $fields[13];       #Duration of session in seconds
    $bytesr = $fields[16];           #Bytes read
    $bytesw = $fields[20];           #Bytes written
    for ($currow = $maxrow; $currow >= 1; $currow--) {
         if ($user[$currow] eq $userid and $close[$currow] eq "--") {
             $close[$currow] = $timestamp;
             last;
         }
     }
}

elsif ($line =~m/Session timed out/) {
    $sessionid = $fields[13];          #Session ID
    $sessionid =~ s/\(session:|\)//g;  #Remove the "(session:" and ")" from the session ID
    $lastacctime = $fields[20];        #Last accessed time
    $lastaccdate = $fields[21];        #Last accessed date
    $lastaccdate =~ s/\).//g;          #Remove the ")" from the last access date
    for ($currow = $maxrow; $currow >= 1; $currow--) {
       if ($user[$currow] eq $userid and $timeout[$currow] eq "--") {
           $timeout[$currow] = $timestamp;
           last;
         }
     }
}

elsif ($line =~m/Max session timeout/) {
    $sessionid = $fields[13];          #Session ID
    $sessionid =~ s/\(session:|\).//g; #Remove the "(session:" and ")" from the session ID
    for ($currow = $maxrow; $currow >= 1; $currow--) {
         if ($user[$currow] eq $userid and $maxtimeout[$currow] eq "--") {
             $maxtimeout[$currow] = $timestamp;
             last;
        }
    }
}

    }
}

#Define the format then output file(s) using printf
#Print the Column headers: UserID, Logon, Logout, Timeout, Maxtimout, Close, Duration
printf VPNREPORT ("%-12s %-12s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s\n", "UserID", "DHCP", "Logon ", "Logout", "Timeout", "Maxtimout", "Close stamp");
print VPNREPORT "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------\n";

#Newest record at top of report
#for ($i = $maxrow; $i >= 1; $i--) {

#Oldest record at top of report
for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxrow; $i++) {
printf VPNREPORT ("%-12s %-12s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s\n", $user[$i], $dhcp[$i], $login[$i], $logout[$    i], $timeout[$i], $maxtimeout[$i], $close[$i]);
}

#Close the input and output files
close (VPNLOG);
close (VPNREPORT);
```

Comment: Please don't write "PERL", because [perl is not an acronym](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f).

Comment: Actually it should be "Perl" according to your link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will do what I initially was seeking to do with the script. I learned a lot about Perl doing this and appreciate everyone's feedback even if I did not incorporate it. Many thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

#This script convert the specified log file to a report showing each user's ID, DHCP Address, Logon time,
#Logout time, Timeout time, and Maxtimout time. 

#Arrays needed for script
my @fields;
my @user;
my @dhcp;
my @login;
my @logout;
my @close;
my @timeout;
my @maxtimeout;

#Scalars needed for script
my $localtime = localtime();
my $input = '/home/user/bin/Temp/log.txt';
my $output = '>/home/user/bin/Temp/vpnreport.txt';
my $line;
my $fields;
my $userid;
my $jdate;
my $jtime;
my $dhcpaddr;
my $srcaddr;
my $sessionid;
my $sessiondur;
my $lastacctime;
my $lastaccdate;
my $bytesr;
my $bytesw;
my $timestamp;
my $maxrow = 0;
my $currow = 0;
my $i = 0;

#Open the log file
open (VPNLOG, $input) or die "Unable to open the input file:$!\n";

#Open the file(s) to be written to in clobber mode
open (VPNREPORT, $output) or die "Unable to open the output file:$!\n";

#Setup to while loop to process each line
while ($line = <VPNLOG>) {
chomp $line; #Remove the line breaks

#Strip the log's timestamp and IP
$line =~ s/.*Juniper:\s(.*)$/$1/;

#If line contains "Administrators" or "(Admin Users)" ignore it and move on to the next line
unless ($line =~ m/Administrators|(Admin Users)|System()/) {
#Split the line into the @fields array on every " " encountered
@fields = split (/ /, $line);
$jdate = $fields[0];                     #Juniper datestamp
$jdate =~ s/-//g;                        #Remove any occurance of "-" from the date stamp
$jtime = $fields[1];                     #Juniper timestamp
$userid = $fields[6];                    #User ID
$userid =~ s/XXXXXXX.|\(.*\)\[(.*)\]//g; #Remove the "XXXXXXX\" preceding the username and the "(Realm)[Role    ]"
                                     #trailing the username
#Normalize and recombine jtime and jdate here:
$timestamp = "$jdate $jtime";
#Check to see if line contains string "VPN Tunneling: Session started for user"

if ($line =~ m/VPN Tunneling: Session started for user/) {
++$maxrow;
$dhcpaddr = $fields[17];          #Destination IP address
$dhcpaddr =~ s/,//g;              #Remove "," trailing the IP address
$user[$maxrow] = $userid;
$dhcp[$maxrow] = $dhcpaddr;
$login[$maxrow] = $timestamp;
$logout[$maxrow] = "--";
$close[$maxrow] = "--";
$timeout[$maxrow] = "--";
$maxtimeout[$maxrow] = "--";
}

elsif ($line =~m/Logout/) {
$dhcpaddr = $fields[10];           #DHCP IP address
$sessionid = $fields[11];          #Session ID
$sessionid =~ s/\(session:|\)//g;   #Remove the "(session:" and ")" from the session ID
for ($currow = $maxrow; $currow >= 1; $currow--) {
    if ($user[$currow] eq $userid and $logout[$currow] eq "--") {
        $logout[$currow] = $timestamp;
        last;
    }
  }
}

elsif ($line =~m/Closed connection/) {
$dhcpaddr = $fields[11];         #DHCP IP Address
$sessiondur = $fields[13];       #Duration of session in seconds
$bytesr = $fields[16];           #Bytes read
$bytesw = $fields[20];           #Bytes written
for ($currow = $maxrow; $currow >= 1; $currow--) {
     if ($user[$currow] eq $userid and $close[$currow] eq "--") {
         $close[$currow] = $timestamp;
         last;
     }
   }
}

elsif ($line =~m/Session timed out/) {
$sessionid = $fields[13];          #Session ID
$sessionid =~ s/\(session:|\)//g;  #Remove the "(session:" and ")" from the session ID
$lastacctime = $fields[20];        #Last accessed time
$lastaccdate = $fields[21];        #Last accessed date
$lastaccdate =~ s/\).//g;          #Remove the ")" from the last access date
for ($currow = $maxrow; $currow >= 1; $currow--) {
   if ($user[$currow] eq $userid and $timeout[$currow] eq "--") {
       $timeout[$currow] = $timestamp;
       last;
     }
   }
}

elsif ($line =~m/Max session timeout/) {
$sessionid = $fields[13];          #Session ID
$sessionid =~ s/\(session:|\).//g; #Remove the "(session:" and ")" from the session ID
for ($currow = $maxrow; $currow >= 1; $currow--) {
     if ($user[$currow] eq $userid and $maxtimeout[$currow] eq "--") {
         $maxtimeout[$currow] = $timestamp;
         last;
    }
  }
}

}
}

#Define the format then output file(s) using printf
#Print the Column headers: UserID, Logon, Logout, Timeout, Maxtimout, Close, Duration
printf VPNREPORT ("%-12s %-12s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s\n", "UserID", "DHCP", "Logon ", "Logout", "Timeout", "Maxtimout", "Close stamp");
print VPNREPORT "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------\n";

#Newest record at top of report
#for ($i = $maxrow; $i >= 1; $i--) {

#Oldest record at top of report
for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxrow; $i++) {
printf VPNREPORT ("%-12s %-12s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s %-18s\n", $user[$i], $dhcp[$i], $login[$i], $logout[$    i], $timeout[$i], $maxtimeout[$i], $close[$i]);
}

#Close the input and output files
close (VPNLOG);
close (VPNREPORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking the regex matching engine so many times (this can become a performance issue if the logs you're going through are voluminous) right off the bat, it seems like there's mileage to be had if you first split each log line up using the hyphen as a delimiter.  `split` is a decent option here.  Hopefully it's more efficient to run regex matches on just the relevant substrings from that point.

As for maintaining context between lines that are not necessarily adjacent, I'm assuming that you will be using the IP addresses as identifiers for sessions.  A hash object will probably suffice as a first-line option for keeping track of which messages you've seen for which IPs.

Comment: I will look into the split command as you suggested. The issue I foresee with using the IP addresses as identifiers for sessions is when the user logs off the vpn and then logs on again they will have the same ip as their last session. Would it be advisable to create my own session identifier from the log or maybe create one after it finds the "Primary authentication successful?" like create a variable after the user name when it finds this and auto increment it after it finds session logout/timeout/maxtimeout using if statments to check and see if a value exists before creating a new line?

Comment: Generating a unique session key (some kind of salt concatenated to the IP for example) is probably a straightforward way to go.  A pretty easy way to check if a particular key exists in a hash is with the `exists` function.

Comment: I never thought of that, I will keep this under consideration as I work my way through this script :)

Comment: It turns out I didn't need a hash to make this work although it would have been helpful. There is a session ID but it only gets reported on timeout and logoff/close events and not session starts :(

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash to save off your "start" information and then access it with when the "end" line comes in.

For example, as you read in each line, I'd parse off the date and check for "Junpier:" (immediately tossing all lines that don't meet the general criteria).  You can probably also check for the key phrases at the same time and then inside the loop do the specific processing needed for each case:

```
my %starts;

while (defined(my $line = <LOGREPORT>)) {
    if ($line =~ s/^... (?:[\d ]\d) \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \S+ Junpier: (\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d) - \S+ - \S+ (\S+) \S+ - (Primary authentication successful|Logout|Closed Connection|Session timed out|Max Session time out)//) {
        my($time, $vpn, $state) = ($1, $2, $3);

        # TODO Normalize $time here if you wish

        if ($state eq 'Primary authentication successful') {
            $starts{$vpn} = $time;

        } elsif (defined(my $start = delete $starts{$time})) {
            # TODO Process other information needed from the line and output one line...
            # TODO Also you can use the normalized ($time - $start) for your duration if it isn't available on the rest of the line.

        } else {
            warn "No 'Primary authentication successful' found for: $vpn\n";
        }
    }
}
```

If you can do it with one massive regex and the rest simple compares, it will go fast.
Of course, is it really critical to be efficient here?

Comment: This seems like a sound idea. I will give it a try. Efficiency is not very critical at the moment since the log files are fairly small and this report will run only once per day but in the future the log files will grow in size due to more users being added so I wanted to learn a more effecient way to parse string elements as opposed to doing a ton of regex matching commands.

Comment: If you don't mind the output by "end" time instead of "start" time, you can do one-pass parsing outputing information as the "end" line is parsed.  If you want it by "start" time, you could either externally sort the output or go to the trouble of gathering all the information in memory, sorting it and then outputing it.

You might also consider outputing CSV and loading it into a spreadsheet for easy manipulation of the output.

Comment: The issue I am facing with the way you have sugested is that log strings lengths and output are all different for each type of event. The other issue is all of the lines in the log contain the timestamp and date that preceed " Juniper:" so throwing those out doesn't make much sense. Not sure if I explained that well enough but I will need to treat all the strings as variable length for each type of event. Reg ex matches may indeed be my only option?

Comment: Actually, the left-portion logs (up to the key words) seemed pretty unified to me (probably because I've seen much worse); my suggestion was to parse that off first and then have unquie regex statements for the right-portion.  To simplify the process, you could start with multiple independent regex statements like you had in your original code, but enhance each regex to parse the entire line.  Once you have it working, determine if it is fast enough.  If not, you can combine all the regex statements into one (possibly combining common pieces and maybe with some monkey business) to gain speed.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I will give it ago :)

Comment: I will probably export a csv version of my report in case we want to manipulate it in an external program. My code should be good enough now to get us what we want to see.

Answer (score 0):

For coding efficiency, I would use regular expressions to isolate the fields needed for each type of line. (I'm assuming that the report needs to be generated a few times a day and execution speed is not an issue.)

I would use a hash of hashes as my data structure. The keys for the first hash would be the userIds. The value for first has is a reference to the second hash. The keys for the second hash would be the operation (authentication, logout, sessionClose, timeOut, maxSession, etc). The value would be the timestamp of the operation. (This would bring all the data for a particular user into a single data structure. I'm also assuming that there is sufficient RAM in the computer to handle all the data in memory. I'm also assuming that only the timestamp of the operation is needed.)

One all the data is captured, I would generate the report by accessing the hash in sorted userId order to generate each line of the report.

Two other thoughts:

I would consider capturing the date as well as the time to capture users being authenticated before midnight and ending the session after midnight. I would store the date time information as seconds since epoch to make duration calculations easier.

In addition I would identify if the log file contains GMT times or local times. You'll need this information to handle daylight saving time changes correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for these thoughts. I had not considered some of the things you had mentioned here especially the time components.

Comment: What would this look like code wise and where in my current code would I put it? I guess I'm strugling to understand how to get the data into the hash line by line.

Comment: A Google search gives many appropriate hits.For example, [hash of hash exammple](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch09_04.htm) seems relevant for your needs.

Comment: I actually was looking at that exact page last night, the thing is their data is all fixed, if I use my scalars in place of the strings would it still populate correctly? Also, they give an example of how to populate the hash structure, would that replace my current split code or would it come before/after it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Once you've isolated the information needed to populate the data structure, the structure does not care about the data source, only the data value. The splits would come first to get at the information and populate the scalars. Then you would use your scalars in place of the strings to populate the data structure. I suggest that you simulate handling one line of the file on paper first to teach yourself the correct order of operations. This simulation should cover all steps from reading the file to printing the report (including report headers if any).

Comment: This helps, I will write a new script to test it out using a smaller data set.

Comment: I was unable to create a hash of hashes using my parsed strings to populate it. The various documentation/tutorials for hash of hashes is very confusing for a newbie like me and doesn't show examples of how to get the data into the structure from parsing lines or scalars. The perl doc breifly mentions subroutines but I am still unclear how to get my data in a hash of hashes structure. I will attempt to experiment more with this data structure when I have more time. I was able to get one hash set populated but I don't know how to go one level deeper. I ended up coding this a different way.